# OpenMDAO 1.5 : Running DOEdriver with array as desvar

Tags: arrays, driver, openmdao

I have used the example described here (http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.0/usr-guide/tutorials/doe-drivers.html?highlight=driver) to show my problem. I want to use the same approach for one component were "params" are array and no longer float . See example below

```
from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Group, Problem, ScipyOptimizer, ExecComp, DumpRecorder, Component


from openmdao.drivers.latinhypercube_driver import LatinHypercubeDriver, OptimizedLatinHypercubeDriver

import numpy as np

class Paraboloid(Component):
    """ Evaluates the equation f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3 """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Paraboloid, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y', val=0.0)

        self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3
        """

        x = params['x']
        y = params['y']

        unknowns['f_xy'] = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        #""" Jacobian for our paraboloid."""

        x = params['x']
        y = params['y']
        J = {}

        J['f_xy', 'x'] = 2.0*x - 6.0 + y
        J['f_xy', 'y'] = 2.0*y + 8.0 + x
        return J
class ParaboloidArray(Component):
    """ Evaluates the equation f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3 """

    def __init__(self):
        super(ParaboloidArray, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('X', val=np.array([0., 0.]))


        self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3
        """

        x = params['X'][0]
        y = params['y'][1]

        unknowns['f_xy'] = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0




top = Problem()
root = top.root = Group()

root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('x', 50.0), promotes=['*'])
root.add('p2', IndepVarComp('y', 50.0), promotes=['*'])
root.add('comp', Paraboloid(), promotes=['*'])

top.driver = OptimizedLatinHypercubeDriver(num_samples=4, seed=0, population=20, generations=4, norm_method=2)
top.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=-50.0, upper=50.0)
top.driver.add_desvar('y', lower=-50.0, upper=50.0)

top.driver.add_objective('f_xy')

top.setup()
top.run()

top.cleanup()
###########################
print("case float ok")
top = Problem()
root = top.root = Group()

root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('X', np.array([50., 50.])), promotes=['*'])

root.add('comp', ParaboloidArray(), promotes=['*'])

top.driver = OptimizedLatinHypercubeDriver(num_samples=4, seed=0, population=20, generations=4, norm_method=2)
top.driver.add_desvar('X', lower=np.array([-50., -50.]), upper=np.array([50., 50.]))

top.driver.add_objective('f_xy')


top.setup()
top.run()

top.cleanup()
```

I obtain the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 102, in <module>
  File "D:\tlefeb\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 1038, in run
    self.driver.run(self)
  File "D:\tlefeb\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\openmdao\drivers\predeterminedruns_driver.py", line 108, in run
    for run in runlist:
  File "D:\tlefeb\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\openmdao\drivers\latinhypercube_driver.py", line 57, in _build_runlist
    design_var_buckets = self._get_buckets(bounds['lower'], bounds['upper'])
  File "D:\tlefeb\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\openmdao\drivers\latinhypercube_driver.py", line 101, in _get_buckets
    bucket_walls = np.linspace(low, high, self.num_samples + 1)
  File "D:\tlefeb\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 102, in linspace
    if step == 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Did I misunderstood  something in my way of coding ?

Comment: What version of OpenMDAO are you running? I also get an error here, but its different than yours. I get a value error...

Comment: Thanks for checking  : I use the 1.5.0 version (and I have Anaconda providing the python )

Answer (score 0):

I get a different error than you, using the the [latest OpenMDAO master](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/commit/f5d0d1c93554b0601b2b194ff5aafcd652513265), but I get an error non-the-less. There isn't anything wrong with the mode, but rather there are some bugs with using array variables for DOEs. I've added a bug-fix [story](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1325582) to the OpenMDAO backlog, which we'll hopefully be able to deal with in the next couple weeks. We'd gladly accept a pull request if you develop a fix before we get to it though.

Comment: For the moment, I can use the "float" approach for DOE but I will check wether I can developp a fix with the help of one of my colleague !